# JQuery: Boostrap Carousel-caption animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a nice script to activate the **animate.css**. It is called [WOW](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html).
I am trying to activate the fadeInRight on every slides carousel-caption, but it doesn't want to work. Here is what I have now:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
      $('.carousel-caption').addClass("wow fadeInRight");
      $('.carousel-caption').attr('data-wow-delay','5s');
})
```

If I avoide using the **slide.bs.carousel** and instead I directly add the classes to all of my 3 slides with different **delay** it will work only for 1 go and when the first slide comes it won't do any effect, which is understandable cause the slider is loaded.

So how to make this code to run on every slide and then when it comes back to the same slide to continue doing the animation ?

Comment: WOW animates when scrolling the page. From the docs --> "it will be invisible until the user scrolls to reveal it.". Using WOW in a carousel is not scrolling the page.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/69740 -- google for stuff there's been a lot of examples I've found.